# Natbib of DOI with bad characters

Tags: natbib, doi

I have a BibTeX file with the following entry:

```
@article{Garbrecht1998,
  title={The treatment of flat areas and depressions in automated drainage analysis of raster digital elevation models},
  author={Martz, L.W. and Garbrecht, J.},
  journal={Hydrological processes},
  volume={12},
  number={6},
  pages={843--855},
  year={1998},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library},
  doi={{10.1002/(SICI)1099-1085(199805)12:6<843::AID-HYP658>3.0.CO;2-R}}
}
```

I'm creating my bibliography with `natbib`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=black,anchorcolor=black,citecolor=black]{hyperref}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
{\scriptsize
\bibliography{refs}}

\end{document}
```

You'll note that the DOI of the BibTeX entry contains some "bad" characters such as `<` and `>`. These should be displayed verbatim in the resulting PDF, but, instead, they are processed into large-angle symbols which cannot be copied and pasted.

How can I get BibTeX+natbib+LaTeX to give me my DOIs verbatim?

Thanks!

Comment: You can create a short DOI without such charaters here: http://shortdoi.org/10.1002/%28SICI%291099-1085%28199805%2912:6%3C843::AID-HYP658%3E3.0.CO;2-R

Answer (score 4):

`\usepackage{doi}` will let you typeset all DOI's "verbatim". It will make them links as well.

Comment: Or you can use `\usepackage{uri}`

Comment: As @HarishKumar says, `uri` is another option. It seems to be newer too, so probably the preferred solution.

Comment: Using the `doi` package with `hyperref` yields an option clash. Using `uri` with `hyperref` does not. If @amorua edits the answer to use `uri`, I will accept it.